# Fuzzy search not working with dismax query parser

Tags: solr, lucene

There is a field in my schema 'fullText' which is of the 'text_en' type, and multivalued.  The term 'tests' is in the fullText field in one document.

In solr, when I try to search using the word 'test', with the standard lucene parser with minimal distance 1, its returning the document.  The query I am using is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?q=fullText:test~1&wt=xml&indent=true
```

But I am doing the same using dismax, and its not returning the document.  The queries I have tried are:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?q=test&wt=xml&indent=true&defType=dismax&qf=fullText~1

http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?q=test~1&wt=xml&indent=true&defType=dismax&qf=fullText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisMax, by design, does not support all lucene query syntax in it's query parameter.  From [the documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin):

> This query parser supports an extremely simplified subset of the Lucene QueryParser syntax. Quotes can be used to group phrases, and +/- can be used to denote mandatory and optional clauses ... but all other Lucene query parser special characters are escaped to simplify the user experience.

Fuzzy queries are one of the things that are not supported.  There is a [request to add it to the `qf` parameter](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-629), if you'd care to take a look, but it has not been implemented.

One good solution would be to go to the [`edismax` query parser](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax), instead.  It's query parameter supports full lucene query parser syntax:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/simple/select?q=test~1&defType=edismax&qf=fullText
```

Comment: With edismax it's working.But i am wondering is there any filter(edit distance filter) for it which i can put in  scheme.xml in section '<analyzer type="query"> .. </analyzer>'  for that field to make my work easier and more simplistic?

Comment: @Shobhit_Geek There are analysis techniques you could use, sure.  N-grams, for instance.  To my mind, none of it is simpler, or usually more effective, than just writing a query that expresses what you need to search for.  The idea of an edit distance filter doesn't really make sense, since analysis can only operate on one half of the comparison at a time.  Not quite sure what you are proposing there.

Comment: N-gram is not helping me. 
I have  4 fields in my document which are book name , author, field, fullText. fullText is basically a multivalued copy text field where i am copying all the fields.To search in fullText i want to use fuzzy search with distance 1.
Say user is searching 'python' then search should happen for all tokens(ython, pthon, pyton, phython , pithon etc.) in fullText. In other fields search should happen in normal way.

If i use the fuzzy search in query then it would use fuzzy search for all the fields. I don't know how to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Write your query that way.  You can override the `qf` fields in the query, using standard lucene syntax:  `q=test fullText:test~1&qf=name author field`

Comment: qf is not supported in standard lucene parser. Anyways,i got your point.One last question what do you mean by :   
'The idea of an edit distance filter doesn't really make sense, since analysis can only operate on one half of the comparison at a time' ?

Comment: Analysis operates on the indexed term at index time, and the query terms at query time. It never has both a source and target at the same time. The goal of analysis is to transform data into a searchable form, like a soundex id, or a set of ngrams, or a word, or word stem. The Levenshtein algorithm determines the distance between two strings. It doesn't provide any way to transform strings to a searchable form.